# Weird behaviour of fill method in different kinds of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have been experimenting with two shapes. First one is a type of frame and its code is below:

( (x,y) is origin of my `UIView` and (w,h) is its size)

```
[bpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
[bpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y)];
[bpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y + h)];
[bpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y + h)];
[bpath closePath];

[bpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + 100, y + 100)];
[bpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + 100, y + 50)];
[bpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + 50, y + 50)];
[bpath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + 50, y + 100)];
[bpath closePath];
```

This gives me following output:

[image]

And second one is a circle inside a circle. Its code is below:

```
[bpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y + h * 0.5)];
[bpath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.5) radius:midx startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];

[bpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.75, y + h * 0.5)];
[bpath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.5) radius:0.25 * w startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
```

And for this I got something like below:

[image]

I applied `[bpath fill]` to both paths. So why there is a difference in fill pattern. (I tried adding `closePath` in 2nd case, but it didn't make any difference).

Also, is there a way to get similar fill pattern as of 1st shape for the 2nd one?
(I know it can be done by adding a second path for inner circle but I want to do it in one path)

**Update**: I noticed that if I use `containsPoint` on 2nd path, it returns `FALSE` when touch point is inside inner circle and returns `TRUE` only when touch point is in between two circles. Similar behaviour is shown by 1st shape also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the second example make a hole, you need to set [`usesEvenOddFillRule`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/usesEvenOddFillRule).

```
bpath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
[bpath fill];
```

Here's my working code:

```
UIBezierPath *bpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGFloat x = rect.origin.x;
CGFloat y = rect.origin.y;
CGFloat w = rect.size.width;
CGFloat h = rect.size.height;
CGFloat midx = (x + w) / 2;

[bpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y + h * 0.5)];
[bpath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.5) radius:midx startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];

[bpath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.75, y + h * 0.5)];
[bpath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.5) radius:0.25 * w startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];

[[UIColor blueColor] set];
bpath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
[bpath fill];
```

Result:

[image: Result image]

**Update:**

After playing around with the code a little, I found out why your first example produces a hole and your second didn't: it's about the *direction* of the paths!

In the first path, the outer square is drawn clockwise while the inner square is drawn counter-clockwise. This seems to make the zero-rule for filling consider the inner rectangle to be "outside".

But the circles are both drawn in the same direction. If you reverse the direction of the inner circle it'll make a hole even without setting `usesEvenOddFillRule`:

```
[bpath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.5) radius:0.25 * w startAngle:2*M_PI endAngle:0 clockwise:NO];
```

(Notice that start and end angle are reversed and `clockwise:NO`).

Comment: As I mentioned in last line, I already tried adding [bpath closePath] and there was no change. I tried usesEvenOddFillRule, but still same result.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the solution. But still wondering about the 1st shape. I didn't set usesEvenOddFillRule for that shape but still fill pattern was correct in that case. Any reasons for that behaviour?

Comment: @blancos: Yes, I played around with your code a little and found the answer. See my edit, it's about the path _directions_.

Comment: Yes, but to make the direction opposite, if you set clockwise of outer circle to NO and inner circle to YES, the problem will re appear. Thanks for the fix and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The second example also needs the [bpath closePath]. The first example contains two closed subpaths, but currently the second example contains just one unclosed path.